# How to access 'req' object in loopback from "access" hook?

Tags: loopbackjs

It seems operation hook "access" does not contains `ctx.req` object.

What i am trying to achieve is that session data should be available in all the models.

Session defined in middleware:

```
 "session": {
     "express-session": {
         "params": {
         "secret": "mysceret",
         "saveUninitialized": true,
         "resave": true
        }
    }
 }
```

In *User.js* :

```
req.session.user = userData;
```

and to access session in `Post` model:

```
Post.observe('access', function(ctx, next) {     
   console.log('ctx.req : ' , ctx.req) // undefined
   ctx.query.filter = { tenantId: ctx.req.session.user.tenantId }; 
   // so cannot able to find session data here.   
   next();
});
```

Express-session : `"express-session": "^1.15.6"`

Loopback version : `"loopback": "^3.0.0"`

What I am missing or I am access session in a wrong way ?
Please some help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get the session? @uday214125

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to heavily borrow from my answer at [accessing current logged in user id in custom route in loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49489531/accessing-current-logged-in-user-id-in-custom-route-in-loopback/49502015#49502015)

> The operation hook context accepts what values you submit to it, as
>   well as a few defaults related to the model, it would never have the
>   userId by default.
>   https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#operation-hook-context-object

**The `ctx` in an operation hook is *not* the same as the `ctx` in a remote method.**

If you want to pass in additional operation hook context values then you must use call a model method manually and send them as the second parameter.

```
model.create({color: 'red'}, {contextValue: 'contextValue', anotherContextValue: 'anotherContextValue'}, (err, obj) => {
   // Callback things...
}
```

Comment: can you look into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271853/store-session-in-operation-hook-loopback

Answer (score 0):

Operation hooks can read the accessToken from `ctx.options` provided you're logged in:
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html#access-the-context-from-operation-hooks

```
Model.observe('access', async ctx => {
  let {options: {accessToken = {}} = {}, ...otherAttributes} = ctx;
  console.log(accessToken);
});
```

You can even set some properties on the accessToken using a middleware hooked onto the `"routes:before"` section, since middlewares hace access to `req` and `req.accessToken`.

Your middleware could say something like:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return function setSession(req, res, next) {
    let {accessToken} = req;
    accessToken.session = req.session;
    next();
  };
};
```

`however`, if you're already doing:

```
 req.session.user = userData;
```

To store the value of the current user onto the session, you can already access that using `accessToken.user()` wherever you can get a reference to the token in question.