# access an external model and request Object in Operational hook `before save`

Tags: node.js, hook, loopbackjs, loopback

I need to access an external model in Org.js (Org.json is the model). I am unable to do it using the ctx. The ctx is also not populating the request object. I might need the url, http method, userId. I have gone through the link here [How to access 'req' object in loopback from "access" hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886004/how-to-access-req-object-in-loopback-from-access-hook) but not quite helpful. I have not been able to replicate the suggestions and pass the models/req object to the operational hook - ctx.

Here is my Org.js

```
module.exports = function (Org) {
  Org.observe('before save', function filterProperties(ctx, next) {
    // Need access to the external Model and the req object here.
    // returns undefined
    let MyCUstomModel  = ctx.Model.MyCUstomModel  
    // returns undefined
    let MyCUstomModel  = ctx.Models.MyCUstomModel 
    next();
  });

};
```

Org.json

```
{
  "name": "Org",
  "plural": "Orgs",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Getting the model in the operation hook**

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#before-save

> Depending on which method triggered this hook, the context will have
>   one of the following sets of properties:
>
> Full save of a single model
>
> Model - the constructor of the model that will be saved
>
> instance - the model instance to be saved. The value is an instance of
>   Model class.

Instead of `let MyCUstomModel  = ctx.Model.MyCUstomModel`

Do `let MyCustomModel = ctx.Model`

**Http context in an access hook**

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html

It seems like you have to pass in the context parameter manually in the remote methods like https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html#write-a-custom-remote-method-with-options

```
Message.findById(messageId, null, options)
      .then(msg => {
```

Comment: Yes I am getting the model undefined using the same way. I am following this snippet here as mentioned. https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Using-current-context.html#access-the-context-from-operation-hooks

Comment: The snippet says to use the `modelName` key.  It literally returns that model's name as a string.

Comment: Hm... I have used the exact same code frankly in the docs and surprisingly its coming undefined. Let me recheck.